# When I run Python file in VS Code Terminal, the output appears and disappears immediately

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I run a Python program in VS Code(`Run Python File`), the terminal does show output, but the output disappears very quickly, almost instantaneously.

Why does this happen? How to solve it?

Below is my `tasks.json`.

---

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "python3",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "G:\\anaconda3\\envs\\pytorch",
            "args": ["${file}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**Edit:** If I install the `Code Runner` plugin and use `Run Code` to run the program, the above situation will not occur.

---

**Edit:** If I run my "python3 test.py" in VS terminal, nothing will happen.

[image]

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you run your "python3 mycode.py" in a terminal window?

Comment: @totalMongot I answered that in my question

Answer (score 0):

With the edit, I think this means there is no output in your program. Could you try to add in your code:

*print("Hello")*

*sleep("50")*

And see whether "Hello" appears ?

Comment: I tried it and it shows 'Hello' within 50 seconds and disappears after 50 seconds. Besides, when I use `ctrl + C` to interrupt the program, it will appear: `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`

Comment: In the past, when I used `ctrl + C` to interrupt the program, the program was terminated directly, and the above `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` would not appear.

Comment: So the behaviour is correct in the batch. The message about "terminate batch job" appears because the program is still running (it is sleeping 50 seconds).
Now do you have the "Hello" as well in the VS terminal?

Comment: I've been talking about VS terminal. I seem to have mistaken the `Terminal Window` you mentioned earlier for `VS Terminal`.

Comment: @Lancdorr Ok so now I think the only issue you have is whether or not you gives ouput in your python code. The only way to help you on that, if you want to follow up, is to show your code and your expectations in your question